# Linq to Entities iQueryable Filter on Filtered results

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable, entities

I'm writing a function to return a collection of data.  Let's assume we have

```
Dim myQuery = (From B In ctx.MyTable.AsQueryable
               Select
                   SomeValue = CType(B.SomeValue, Decimal?),
                   AnotherValue = CType(B.AnotherValue, Decimal?))

myQuery = myQuery.Where(Function(x) x.SomeValue<50)
Dim myInterimResult = myQuery.ToList
```

How do I query `MyInternalResult` on the server filtering only through the results of original query?

What i'm aiming at is a double filter.  as in let's say I want to first filter Some value so that only values <50 are returned... and the a secondary filter that filters the result of the previous further...

WIll I have to do .ToList on my first iqueryable filter and then only filter the results local in .net collection?  My concern is that even though not at the moment my results can get quite large 10000+ records. i'd like to keep my workload to be done on sql server rather than in memory. the code I have is quite large so I just made a simple example to illustrate my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you shouldn't call `ToList` between applying different filtering conditions. Just call `Where` again:

```
Dim myQuery = (From B In ctx.MyTable.AsQueryable
               Select
                   SomeValue = CType(B.SomeValue, Decimal?),
                   AnotherValue = CType(B.AnotherValue, Decimal?))

myQuery = myQuery.Where(Function(x) x.SomeValue < 50)

myQuery = myQuery.Where(Function(x) x.AnotherValue < 20)
```

Comment: So let's say the first iteration I wanted to show deals that were somevalue <50.... and THEN the user put in a secondary filter that he wants to show items <60.... in this scenario are the items between 50 and 60 included?  my intent is that the 2nd set of where clauses only derives from results of the first

Comment: Okay I've tested and adding multiple where's on same fields seems to filter the previous.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, all conditions are evaluated. The further ones don't override previously added, even when you filter based on the same column.